# Can I use Bind Monster in addition to the combat check?

Tags: arkham-horror

The spell says:

> Cast and Discard this spell to pass one Combat check. You must roll successes equal to the monster's toughness to cast this spell. This spell doesn't work on Ancient Ones.

If I fail to cast this spell, do I still get to make the normal combat check with my fight skill level as a second attempt to pass the combat check, or is this done in place of the fight skill level check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fail to cast a spell, none of its effects happen. So you're left exactly where you started: you have a combat check to make. Of course, Bind Monster is two-handed, so... you won't have any weapons and may not fare too well in the check.

(Side note: combat checks are a special kind of fight check; this is a combat check, not just a fight check.)

Comment: Can you give a little detail into why combat checks aren't fight checks? I see it mentioned in the Fight section and am uncertain.

Comment: I should have been slightly clearer; they're still a kind of fight check so for example [Grapple](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Grapple) will work. But it's not the same thing as a generic fight check. A fight check is a check which uses purely your fight skill, and will be written like "make a Fight (-1) check." A combat check uses your fight skill (with any modifiers) along with anything that affects combat checks. For example, weapons will say something like "+4 to Combat checks", so they apply only to combat checks, not fight checks.